# a proof for a probably common problem?

Tags: proof-verification

Can someone provide a proof for the following problem? I know that this might be a common proof to some common problem that I am yet to know, and that if someone would leave a proof it 
would give me a deeper understanding of powers.

$$x^{-n}=\frac {x}{x^{(n+1)}}$$

Comment: Multiply both sideds with $x^{n+1}$ (of course assuming taht $x\ne 0$, which must be assumed anyway)?

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $x^{n+1}= x\cdot x^n$ and $x^{-n} = \frac 1n$ so:
$$x^{-n}=\frac{x}{x \cdot x^n} \rightarrow \frac{1}{x^n}=\frac{1}{x^n}$$

Comment: You're welcome and remember to +1 and accept!